# asp.net: gridView rotate background color. setting a index column in a DataTable?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

two questions about grindView and dataTable.

1. how can i set a dataTable index which always counts one up?
   e.g. i make a column: 
   `Columns.Add(new DataColumn("#"));`
   and when i add a row, the # column is automatically increased?
2. how can i rotate the background color in a gridView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Set Rowstyle for gridview backcolour e.g.

    <asp:GridView id="gd" runat="Server">

          <RowStyle BackColor="Red" />

    </asp:GridView>

If u want it from Code side then 

For particular Column    
    gridview.Columns[0].ItemStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
For grid
       gridview.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```